Не создаётся контейнер в докер с minikube
У меня такая проблема, что при написании команды minikube start, у меня начинается загрузка и при этом она идёт очень долго потом она переключается на qemu. Ниже указаны логи
minikube start
  minikube v1.33.1 на Fedora 39
✨  Automatically selected the docker driver. Other choices: qemu2, none, ssh
  Using Docker driver with root privileges
❗  For an improved experience it's recommended to use Docker Engine instead of Docker Desktop.
Docker Engine installation instructions: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/#server
  Starting "minikube" primary control-plane node in "minikube" cluster
  Pulling base image v0.0.44 ...
  Скачивается Kubernetes v1.30.0 ...
    > preloaded-images-k8s-v18-v1...:  342.90 MiB / 342.90 MiB  100.00% 5.22 Mi
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...
  StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds
  docker "minikube" container is missing, will recreate.
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...
  Failed to start docker container. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: recreate: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds
❗  Startup with docker driver failed, trying with alternate driver qemu2: Failed to start host: recreate: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds
  Deleting "minikube" in docker ...
  Removing /home/network_fox/.minikube/machines/minikube ...
  Removed all traces of the "minikube" cluster.
  Automatically selected the builtin network
❗  You are using the QEMU driver without a dedicated network, which doesn't support `minikube service` & `minikube tunnel` commands.
  Downloading VM boot image ...
    > minikube-v1.33.1-amd64.iso....:  65 B / 65 B [---------] 100.00% ? p/s 0s
    > minikube-v1.33.1-amd64.iso:  314.16 MiB / 314.16 MiB  100.00% 2.59 MiB p/
  Starting "minikube" primary control-plane node in "minikube" cluster
  Creating qemu2 VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB, Disk=20000MB) ...\ 

И да, при прописывание драйвера у меня выскакивают следующие логи
minikube start --driver=docker
  minikube v1.33.1 на Fedora 39
✨  Используется драйвер docker на основе конфига пользователя
  Using Docker driver with root privileges
❗  For an improved experience it's recommended to use Docker Engine instead of Docker Desktop.
Docker Engine installation instructions: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/#server
  Starting "minikube" primary control-plane node in "minikube" cluster
  Pulling base image v0.0.44 ...
  Creating docker container (CPUs=4, Memory=2200MB) ...
  StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds
  docker "minikube" container is missing, will recreate.
  Creating docker container (CPUs=4, Memory=2200MB) ...
  Failed to start docker container. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: recreate: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds

❌  Exiting due to DRV_CREATE_TIMEOUT: Failed to start host: recreate: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds
  Предложение: Try 'minikube delete', and disable any conflicting VPN or firewall software
  Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7072

И мне пишется что у меня может быть включён VPN, но я всё проверил и никакого VPN у меня не подключено.
Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему. Просто я хочу чтобы всё запускалось в Docker. Если что у меня Fedora 39, мб эта инфа чем-то поможет.
